# Roslyn workspace API not loading properly for a third-party solution

Tags: c#, msbuild, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm trying to enumerate all `Document` items in each `Project` instance using the Roslyn Workspace API for a third-party solution that has been provided to me. My code looks like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild;


string slnPath = "ThirdPartySolution.sln";

MSBuildWorkspace workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
Solution s = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync("ThirdPartySolution.sln")
);

foreach (Project p in s.Projects)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(p.Documents.Count());
        
    foreach (Document d in p.Documents)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + d.Name);
    }
}

workspace.Dispose();
```

The code runs without errors when I build and run using .NET Core. Furthermore the names of the projects within this solution all appear to print out to the terminal. However, the count of `Document` instances in each `Project` object always turns out to be 0. I know this isn't the case, so I added the following code to try to diagnose the problem:

```
foreach (WorkspaceDiagnostic diagnostic in workspace.Diagnostics)
{
    Console.WriteLine(diagnostic.Message);
}
```

One of the diagnostic messages I'm getting is as follows:

> The imported project "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Current\Microsoft.Common.props" was not found.
> Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Current\Microsoft.Common.props" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.408\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.props

I checked for the existence of the mentioned paths `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Current\Microsoft.Common.props"` does not exist while `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.408\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.props` does exist.

I find this strange because the solution builds fine when I select the `Buid > Build Solution` item from the main menu in Visual Studio 2022. It also builds fine from the command line using `msbuild`.

What could be going wrong here?

## Edit

Working solution:

```cs
// Program.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild;
using Microsoft.Build.Locator;

string slnPath = "ThirdPartySolution.sln";

MSBuildLocator.RegisterDefaults();

MSBuildWorkspace workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
Solution s = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(slnPath
);

foreach (WorkspaceDiagnostic diagnostic in workspace.Diagnostics)
{
    Console.WriteLine(diagnostic.Message);
}

foreach (Project p in s.Projects)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(p.Documents.Count());
        
    foreach (Document d in p.Documents)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + d.Name);
    }
}

workspace.Dispose();
```

In addition to this, you have to make sure that `ExcludeAssets="runtime"` is set in your project file for all `Microsoft.Build.*` package references *except* for `Microsoft.Build.Locator`:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build" Version="17.7.2"
        ExcludeAssets="runtime"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Framework" Version="17.7.2"
        ExcludeAssets="runtime"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Locator" Version="1.6.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core" Version="17.7.2"
        ExcludeAssets="runtime"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild" Version="4.7.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Also check [this](https://gist.github.com/DustinCampbell/32cd69d04ea1c08a16ae5c4cd21dd3a3#setting-up-msbuild) link for more details.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Roslyn Workspace API but I'm guessing that to find the documents in a project, MSBuild (or an equivalent internal library) is used to load the project and perform the [evaluation phase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/build-process-overview?view=vs-2022). Is the project an SDK style project that targets .NET Framework?

Comment: The solution appears to comprise of SDK style projects that either target .NET Framework or .NET Standard

Comment: .NET Framework is a required component of the "ASP.NET and Web Development" and the ".NET Desktop Development" workloads in the VS Installer. Do you have either or both of those workloads installed for Visual Studio 2022? .NET Framework is Windows-only and is not available in the cross-platform .NET install (i.e. `C:\Program Files\dotnet\...`)

Comment: As I mentioned in the OP I can build the solution fine in VS2022. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: The project that you are trying to parse builds fine, is that correct? It wasn't clear from the OP which project you meant.

Comment: The *solution* I'm trying to parse builds fine in VS 2022 but not using Roslyn.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255803/discussion-between-jonathan-dodds-and-user32882).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently (as of this writing in October 2023), you'll [need to use the MSBuildLocator to register an instance of MSBuild before using MSBuildWorkspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/find-and-use-msbuild-versions?view=vs-2022#use-microsoftbuildlocator). If you're trying to analyze a SDK style project you should also have your app be targeting .NET Core as opposed to .NET Framework.

I'm emphasizing the "currently" for the first part of this answer because I'm actually working on removing that requirement in [this pull request](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/70469) so I would expect by the time the 4.9.0 NuGet packages ship, that'll no longer be a requirement and the user's original code should have just worked. So any future users of this quesiton, please check if that support is merged into the Roslyn build you're using.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will edit my answer with the full details of how I got things to work

Comment: @user32882 Nice writeup!